# dc.js overlaying 2 charts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

sorry if there is already another question that can help me but I didn`t find it.

I have a database with persons in which the columns are id, name, gender, height and weight.

```
id,name,gender,height,weight
1,Kinsley,Male,168,90
2,Dimitry,Male,177,61
3,Martica,Female,152,76
4,Brittni,Female,156,88
5,Phillip,Male,161,78
6,Sofie,Female,161,71
7,Avril,Female,163,55
8,Allistir,Male,161,75
9,Emelda,Female,154,66
10,Camella,Female,153,52
11,Baudoin,Male,168,55
12,Ava,Female,180,52
13,Candida,Female,153,56
14,Curtis,Male,161,63
15,Mozelle,Female,167,59
16,Hermina,Female,180,90
17,Pammy,Female,159,55
18,Zechariah,Male,178,95
19,Kerwin,Male,150,69
20,John,Male,179,70
21,Shayne,Male,176,57
22,Hewie,Male,171,55
23,Murray,Male,179,54
24,Jarret,Male,158,76
25,Archer,Male,174,53
26,Emmy,Female,168,85
```

Here is how I fetch the data.

```
 d3.csv("/local-test-data/people_hw.csv",
      data => <IDataFromCsv>{
        id: +data["id"],
        gender: data["gender"],
        name: data["name"],
        height: +data["height"],
        weight: +data["weight"],
      }
    )
      .then((data: IDataFromCsv[]) => {
        this.sourceDataWDays = data;
        this.sourceDataWDays.forEach(d => {
          if (d.gender === "Male") {
            d.newData = 1;
          } else {
            d.newData = 2;
          }
        });
        return this.sourceDataWDays;
      })
      .then((data) => this.loadCharts(data))

  };

sourceDataWDays: IDataFromCsv[];

export interface IDataFromCsv {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  gender: string,
  height: number,
  weight: number,
  newData: number,
}
```

I`m using dc.js, d3.js, and crossfilter to create this dashboard and angular & typescript to create the web app.

I created 2 charts using, one bar chart that shows how many persons by gender I have in the database and another is a series chart (with 2 lines) that shows the weight of the persons. (x-axis the weight and y-axis for Male or Female) Everything fine until now.
[image: the bar chart]

[image: the line chart]

**What I want?**

I want to overlap the charts.
I want the second to be hidden if the first has no filter. If the first has 1 filter I want the bar one to get opacity for the bars (opacity: 01), hide the axis, and instead of its axis, I want the second one`s axis and the lines to pe over the bars.

Something like this but with the axis:

[image: Something like this but with the axis]

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
  loadCharts(data: IDataFromCsv[]): void {

    let ndx: Crossfilter<IDataFromCsv> = crossfilter(data);

    this.loadWeightChart(ndx);
    this.loadGenderChart(ndx);

    dc.renderAll();
  };

  loadGenderChart(ndx: Crossfilter<IDataFromCsv>): void {

    this.genderChart = dc.barChart("#genderChart");

    let gDimension: any = ndx.dimension(d => d.gender);
    let gGroup: any = gDimension.group().reduceCount();

    this.genderChart
      .width(768)
      .height(480)
      .dimension(gDimension)
      .group(gGroup)
      .x(d3.scaleOrdinal())
      .colorAccessor((d, i) => i)
      .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
      .on("filtered.monitor", genderChart => {
        if (genderChart.filters().length === 1) {
          d3.select("#genderChart").selectAll("svg").style("opacity", "0.2");
          d3.select("#genderChart").selectAll("g .axis").style("visibility", "hidden");
          dc.redrawAll();
        } else {
          d3.select("#genderChart").selectAll("svg").style("opacity", "1");
          d3.select("#genderChart").selectAll("g .axis").style("visibility", "visible");
        }
      })
      .brushOn(false)
      .yAxisLabel("Count")
      .xAxisLabel("Gender")
  };

  loadWeightChart(ndx: Crossfilter<IDataFromCsv>): void {

    this.weightChart = dc.seriesChart("#weightChart");

    let wdDimension: any = ndx.dimension(data => { return [data.gender, data.weight] });
    let wdGroup: any = wdDimension.group().reduceCount();

    this.weightChart
      .width(800)
      .height(500)
      .chart(c => {
        return dc.lineChart(c)
      })
      .dimension(wdDimension)
      .group(wdGroup)
      .xAxisLabel("Weight")
      .yAxisLabel("Count")
      .elasticY(true)
      .brushOn(false)
      .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([50, 100]))
      .seriesAccessor(d => d.key[0])
      .keyAccessor(d => +d.key[1])
      .valueAccessor(d => +d.value)
  };
```

and HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="genderChart">
      <div class="forReset" style="margin:10px 0 -10px 0;">
        <a class="reset" (click)="resetGenderChart();" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="weightChart">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can I do it starting from what I did? how?

I don't care what kind of chart I'm using as long as I got what I need (the bar chart with the lines overlying). I`m beginner in dc.js & d3.js & cross filter. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I’m having some trouble visualizing what you are trying to do. One problem is that you keep referring to “bars” but these are line charts, so I guess you mean “lines”? Also, you say you want to “overlap” the charts, but you also say you want to hide one when the other is shown, so I guess you mean that you want to “replace” a chart and display another one in the same place? Finally, I don’t know what “opacity 01” means; this is usually percentage or a number from 0 to 1. Please edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I'll try to make it simpler. I have 2 charts. One  [bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Wyt.png) and the second one [line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgdCT.png). I want to overlap the charts: When I click on one of the bars from the bar chart to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP3DZ.jpg) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBjuW.png). In the last 2 imgs I don`t have the axis because I set the bar chart axis to hidden because I want instead of them the line char axis. About the imgs from my post, you were right...I put there a line chart instead of a bar chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing lines and bars in the same chart is achieved with the [composite chart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/composite-bar-line.html).

[image: composite chart screenshot]

If the bars have a different scale from the lines, you could use the [right axis](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/right-axis.html) feature to draw both of them filling the height of the chart.

[image: right axis screenshot]

If needed, you could hide the right axis with CSS

```
.dc-chart g.axis.yr {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use X Axis on top, also as the Y Axis?

Comment: Looks like we've provided an [example for row charts](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/row-top-axis.html) which you may be able to adapt. It takes a little custom code, esp since it's not possible to detect which axis was supplied. [This issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1433) has some details.